# Determine if a number being dialed is in the contact list

Tags: android, android-emulator

Im trying to write my first android app. Coming from a winmobile phone, there was an option to block my outgoing caller id, not so with android.
Ive got a small app started that will add *67 to outgoing calls the problem is it adds *67 to every call, I dont want to add this to people in my contact list so they can see that its me thats calling. I just want to block my caller Id to unknown numbers

this is all the code so far and its working in the emulator, the basics came from http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1151

```
public class OutgoingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String originalNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    String myNumber = originalNumber;
    String msg3 = "Caller Id Already Blocked " + myNumber;
    String msg4 = "Blocking Caller Id " + myNumber;

    if(myNumber.contains("*67") == true)  
    {  
                Toast.makeText(context, msg3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.setResultData(originalNumber);

    } else {  
            Toast.makeText(context, msg4, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.setResultData("*67" + originalNumber);
        final String newNumber = this.getResultData();
        String msg = "Caller Id Blocked - Old number " + originalNumber + ", new number " + newNumber;
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } 

 }}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here? Im not sure how to check the number im dialing against the contact list

Answer (score 0):

what are you asking is that you want to fetch the call log details.You can do so:

```
Uri UriCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(UriCalls, null, null, null, null);
```

refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) for more clearity.

Comment: from what im reading at the link you gave this is only for recent calls. that bit of code above will handle recently dialed calls fine. If I select a number from my contact list, it will add *67 to it. I dont want it to do that. So what im trying to do is determine if the number im dialing is in my contact list dont add *67 to the number

Comment: are you asking to fetch contact list from from the contacts then try this:http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/contacts.html

Comment: no, what im asking is determine if the number being dialed is in the contact list, without selecting from a list just as it is being dialed